# How can i override the windows.onbeforeunload function only for an iframe?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, removeeventlistener

I have an eventlistener

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(evt){
//causes pop up 
}
```

I need to  override it with  another event listener  for an iframe(Download case here). The below code is not working

```
var tIFrame = document.getElementById('Download');

iFrame.contentWindow.addEventListener('beforeunload', wrappedFn, false);
```

iFrame.addEventListener('beforeunload', wrappedFn, true);

Comment: You'll need to actually override it by reassigning `contentWindow.onbeforeunload`. Using `addEventListener` just adds a second listener.

Comment: @Bergi var unloadfunc= function(){}      iFrame.contentWindow.onbeforeunload=unloadfunc;  I have tried it in this way also. Still it calls the window.onbeforeunload function.

Comment: Are you certain that the assignment happens after the assignment inside the iframe?

Comment: @Bergi    Yes, i can see in debug env, it is getting assigned. But still it calls the wndow.onbeforeunload on executing location.href=cmd .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Bergi for the hint. The below code worked for me

```
var iFrame=document.getElementById('Download');
iFrame.contentWindow.onbeforeunload=function(){}
iFrame.contentWindow.location.href=sCmd;
```